# hibernate4: A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to use Hibernate annotations for writing a model class for my database tables.

I have two tables each having a primary key `User` and `ChartDetails`.

```
package com.winnow.springservice.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


//User Entity class mapped with hibernate
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "all" })
public class User implements Serializable
{

@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
public String user_Id;

@Column(name="user_name")
public String userName;
public String password;

@Column(name="last_login")
public String last_Login;

@Column(name="role_id")
public int role_Id;
public int status;




public String getUser_Id() {
    return user_Id;
}

public void setUser_Id(String user_Id) {
    this.user_Id = user_Id;
}

public String getLast_Login() {
    return last_Login;
}

public void setLast_Login(String last_Login) {
    this.last_Login = last_Login;
}

public int getRole_Id() {
    return role_Id;
}

public void setRole_Id(int role_Id) {
    this.role_Id = role_Id;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {

    System.out.println("username"+userName);
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password)
{
    System.out.println("password "+password);
    this.password = password;
}


}
```

Chart details

```
package com.winnow.springservice.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Chart_Details")
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "all" })
public class ChartDetails implements Serializable
{

@Id
@Column(name="chart_id")
public int chartId;

@Id
@Column(name="chart_type_id")
public int chartTypeId;

@Column(name="chart_name")
public String chartName;

@Column(name="x_axis")
public String x_axis;

@Column(name="y_axis")
public String y_axis;

@Column(name="z_axis")
public int z_axis;

@Column(name="chart_filter_id")
public int chartFilterId;

@Column(name="is_data_table")
public boolean isDataTable;

@Column(name="dataset_id")
public int datasetId;

@Column(name="user_id")
public int userId;


@Column(name="project_id")
public int projectId;

}
```

And I have one more table – `ChartsStarredBy` – which has `userId` and `chart_id` as foreign keys from the above two tables.

But I am unable to find how I can reference these constraints in the `ChartsStarredBy` table.

```
package com.winnow.springservice.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;


@Entity
@Table(name="Chart_Starred_By")
@SuppressWarnings(value = { "all" })
public class ChartsStarredBy implements Serializable
{

@Id
public int id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date starred_date;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_chart_id4")
private  ChartDetails chart_details;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_user_id4")
private User user;

public Date getStarred_date() 
{
    return starred_date;
}

public void setStarred_date(Date starred_date) 
{
    this.starred_date = starred_date;
}

public User getUser() 
{
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) 
{
    this.user = user;
}

public ChartDetails getChart_details() {
    return chart_details;
}

public void setChart_details(ChartDetails chart_details) {
    this.chart_details = chart_details;
}

}
```

Please help me achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please cut down source code before posting here. Do not bore us with auto-generated JavaDoc. Use consistent indentation so the source code highlighting will work. All this is a courtesy to the people that you expect help from.

Comment: What does the title of your question mean? Is it an error message you are getting? I cannot see any “Hibernate annotations” in your code – it’s all standard JPA.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you should create an integer id for User table which is primary key. Here in your code you creating it as String type.**

You are doing wrong here

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_chart_id4")
private  ChartDetails chart_details;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_user_id4")
private User user;
```

You have IDs in User table & ChartDetails table as

```
@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
public String user_Id;

AND

@Id
@Column(name="chart_id")
public int chartId;
```

So when you refer to id of another class you should give name of that id in **@JoinColumn**. Just like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "chartId")
private  ChartDetails chart_details;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_Id")
private User user;
```

You can also use **@ForeignKey(name = "user_Id")** annotation from Hibernate like this

```
@ManyToOne
@ForeignKey(name = "user_Id")
private User    user;
```

Example tutorial :- [Hibernate One To Many Annotation Tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/)